# GhostScript - ImageMagick converts pdf to image to odd letters when converting Microsoft Print to PDF files

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, centos7, ghostscript

***NOTICE: Watch updates at bottom.***

I am building an API which supposed to convert PDF to base64 images (doesn't matter which type - jpg, jpeg, png..).

The API is built with NodeJS on CentOS 7.5 x64.

I have searched all over the web for npm packages which converts pdf to images, the very most of them uses ImageMagick and GhostScript (The others doesn't seem to work). These packages work well on code but the problem starts when GhostScript does it job.

For example, a simple pdf page with text will look like this after conversion:
[image: example of pdf conversion]

This is the output in shell:

```
  **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by:
   **** >>>> Microsoft: Print To PDF <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

I have tried to convert the images with shell commands ended up with the same outputs.

Thanks by advance.

**UPDATE:**
Converting [a sample pdf file](http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf) which probably was not printed to pdf by Microsoft worked fine, maybe this is the problem?

**UPDATE 2:**
**After converting a few more pdfs it turns out that this is Microsoft Print to PDF files only that making this problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported as a bug to the Ghostscript Bugzilla [here](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699647)

As can be seen from the thread, this is due to using an old version of Ghostscript, and has been fixed at some point in the past. So the problem is due to using old (in this case more than 5 years old) software.

Comment: The link is invalid, but I was reported the bug on the same day I posted this question, so I suggest you meant this one: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699647

Comment: I fixed the URL, it was a copy/paste error. FWIW the reason that old versions of Ghostscript don't work is because the CIDFont embedded by the Microsoft Print to PDF feature is broken. Ghostscript was updated to work around the Microsoft bug